# Menu LI doesn't fit in menu until the mouseover

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building a site for a friend's new charity: http://www.ukraineaid.org

!I want the Ukrainian Orphanages to be on same line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bskjd.png)

How can I edit the CSS to make the Ukrainian Orphanages appear of the same line, not split into two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap` to `.sf-menu li li a` like this:

```
.sf-menu li li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will prevent any word from breaking on a white space. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: I don't see .sf-menu li li a  in the /style/style.css

Answer (score 1):

Changing the width of `.sf-menu li li` to 180px; should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In .sub-menu li a {} change width:auto; to width:175px;

Comment: I don't see .sub-menu li a {} in the stylesheet.

Comment: .sub-menu li a should be in your style.css. If it's not you can always paste the following anywhere in that sheet: .sub-menu li a {width:175px;}